# Bounty completed notification comes too early

Tags: bug, bounties, notifications

Today I logged in to SO and found a notification saying that my bounty was completed 58 minutes before it would actually complete.

[image]

At that time, the question was listed on top of the featured questions, confirming that the bounty was still active and not in grace period.

Not sure if this was the wrong message at the right time or the right message an hour too early.

#### Update

I received an email from StackOverflow about an hour before my bounty would expire with this text:

> Reminder: Your Bounty Ended!
>
> Your bounty on the question … Why does Chrome produce 1099 digits
>   after the dot for (.1).toString(3)?
>
> … ended and will be auto-closed after the 24-hour grace period
>   expires.